# File Filter Search in Java

Tags: java, stream

I'm trying to implement a class, which responsibility is to search for files in an exact directory. The class accepts a list of parameters from the user (e.g. extension, name, size, last modified date, etc.), then filters the directory with all these parameters. Doing that, using the Chain Responsibility pattern, i.e. I have different filters, each responsible for an exact filter operation (all operations are done with Java Stream API). 
The problem is:
Where to store all these String parameters that i get from the user and is it correctly to pass this whole pack through my filters?

Moreover, if you have some comments or remarks on the approach I have chosen for copying with my task, and if there is a better one, will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't store them anywhere to me, just create the predicates and pass those, your method could accept a `List` of these `Predicate`s and you can reduce them to a single one, something along the lines:

```
private <T> Predicate<T> reduced(List<Predicate<T>> nameAndExtension) {
    return nameAndExtension
            .stream()
            .reduce(s -> true,
                    (left, right) -> left.and(right));
}

private void test(List<Predicate<String>> nameAndExtension, List<Predicate<Long>> sizeAndDateAsLong) {

    Predicate<String> first = reduced(nameAndExtension);
    Predicate<Long> second = reduced(sizeAndDateAsLong);

    // apply the above

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the Predicate itsel should hold these parameters and user then should combine these predicates with and(Predicate<>), or(Predicate<>).

One solution is to implement FileFilter and call it with File.listFiles(FileFilter), but this does not support combining of multiple FileFilter classes.

Better solution is to implement Predicate in this way:

ExtensionPredicate.java:

```
public class ExtensionPredicate implements Predicate<File> {

String extension;

public ExtensionPredicate(String extension) {
    this.extension = extension;
}

@Override
public boolean test(File file) {
    return file != null && file.getName().endsWith(extension);
}}
```

SizePredicate.java:

```
public class SizePredicate implements Predicate<File> {

long min;
long max;

public SizePredicate(long min, long max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

@Override
public boolean test(File file) {
    return file != null && file.length() >= min && file.length() < max;
}}
```

Usage:

```
public class PredicatesTest {
@Before
public void createFiles() throws Exception{
    File directory = new File(Paths.get("myStuff").toUri());
    directory.mkdirs();
    new File(directory.getPath(),"a.csv").createNewFile();
    new File(directory.getPath(),"b.txt").createNewFile();
}

@After
public void removeFiles() throws Exception{
    File directory = new File(Paths.get("myStuff").toUri());
    for (File f: directory.listFiles()){
        f.delete();
    }
    directory.delete();
}

@Test
public void testBoth() throws Exception{
    List<File> result = Arrays.asList(new File(Paths.get("myStuff").toUri()).listFiles())
            .stream()
            .filter(new ExtensionPredicate(".txt").and(new SizePredicate(0, 100)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    TestCase.assertEquals(1, result.size());


}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution you've provided. Appreciated and taken into consideration :)